# How do lyophilic colloids reduce surface tension?

Tags: physical-chemistry, surface-chemistry, surfactants, colloids

It's given in my textbook that the surface tension of lyophilic/hydrophilic solutions is lower than water.

But my intuition says, since in lyophilic solutions the interaction between a lyophilic colloid and water molecules would be more than it would be in between two water molecules, then the surface tension would increase. But my textbook says otherwise. What am I missing?